Save file classes in their own directories after build process
is it possible to save project file structure after sencha app build production/development/testing without concatenating?
There is bundle property in app.json but it's not working:
"js": [
    {
        "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": false // default is true, 
    }

Also i tried turning off the compressor:
"compressor": {
    "type": "none"

but it doesn't matter.
After "bundle" is set to "false" the result is:


The easiest way would be to do a Testing build instead of a production build.
You will not have the file structure, but it is neither minified nor uglified
sencha app build testing

Secondly to day you do not need the slicer anymore. Set the slider to null
"slicer": null

If you anyways have to keep the filestructure, you can still load the ext-all.js and keep your file-structure (just copy paste the full project).

Thank you for useful advice. But what do you think about file structure: Is this even possible in Ext7?

I added a line about that at the end.
